# Is MVC built on top of web forms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am reading a book (ultra-fast asp.net 4.5), it says "although asp.net mvc has grown substainitially since it's introduction, Microsoft originally build it on top of web forms".

What is this really mean ? MVC runs web forms functions behind the scene ?

Comment: I believe the default view engine originally used web forms but it has since been replaced with razor.

Comment: The view engine behind MVC is the same that asp.net uses. Microsoft create MVC to prove that is possible to apply patterns, in this case MVC, to asp.net.

Comment: You can choose others view engines to work with MVC, Razor is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "built on top of WebForms" is misleading and inaccurate.

It's true that MVC is built on ASP.NET, and the pipeline is very similar to WebForms up to a point, however what makes WebForms what it is, is the server control architecture, which MVC has never supported fully.

Yes, it's true that MVC originally used WebForms view engine, and you can still use WebForms as a View Engine, but this was essentially used only as a templating engine, and did not have full WebForms support.  At best, you could say that WebForms was sort of "bolted on" to MVC rather than "built on top of" it.

The fact that you could always replace the WebForms View engine (even in MVC 1) with another (say Spark engine or nHaml) shows how false that statement is.